# OAuth EWS Authentication without CleintSecret

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

We are currently using EWS to interface with our mail server to process emails.

With One-Factor Authentication being turned off, we are currently working to get OAuth implemented.

The EWS application has been registered, but our security/IF team is pushing back on Client Secrets because

"If we use app permissions (client id/secret) then if that secret is ever breached someone could read/write any mailbox".

I am trying to see if there is a way to delegate permissions of a user through OAuth?

I have found some code snippets but I get this error when I try to pass a username/password in

*Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS53000: Device is not in required device state: compliant. Conditional Access policy requires a compliant device, and the device is not compliant. The user must enroll their device with an approved MDM provider like Intune.*

Comment: Looks like the admin of your company has set a conditional access policy: [Require device to be marked as compliant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/require-managed-devices#require-device-to-be-marked-as-compliant). This option requires a device to be registered with Azure AD, and also to be marked as compliant. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication.acquiretokenbyusernamepassword?view=azure-dotnet) and either registering my device or asking for them to relax the policy.